# Wordpress loop generates same name of list elements, If post number is less them query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a list of my most 4 recent posts, but if I have less then 4 posts, 4 li elements wont be generated. Is there a way to create a lopp with empity li elements when posts_per_page is less than 4?

```
<ul class="slider sp">
<?php
$ids = get_field('related', false, false);
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
$thumbnail = get_field('image0');
if(empty($thumbnail)){ $thumbnail = APP_URL . "images/cms/no-image.png"; $borderclass = "hasborder";}
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="imager">
                <div class="img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>);"></div>
            </div>
            <p class="ttl">
            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            </p>
            <p class="price"><?php echo the_field('a-price'); ?>円（税別）</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The `$post_count` property of the WP_Query object gets you the number of posts that get displayed, so calculate the difference, and then use a simple `for` loop to output the empty LI elements …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the post count

```
<?php $count = $custom_posts->post_count; ?>
```

then if the count is less than 4 you can print remaining li depending on that

```
<ul class="slider sp">
    <?php
    $ids = get_field('related', false, false);
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post__in' => $ids,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
$count = $query->post_count;
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $thumbnail = get_field('image0');
    if(empty($thumbnail)){ $thumbnail = APP_URL . "images/cms/no-image.png"; $borderclass = "hasborder";}
    ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="imager">
                    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>);"></div>
                </div>
                <p class="ttl">
                <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                </p>
                <p class="price"><?php echo the_field('a-price'); ?>円（税別）</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile;
        $count = 4 - $count;
        if($count > 0){
           for( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){echo '<li></li>';}} endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried but it displays nothing, even having 2 posts.

Comment: can you edit your code so i can check what causing the issue.

Comment: `$count = $custom_posts->post_count;` did you change `$custom_posts` to `$query`?

Comment: Thank you very much it did work. How should I do If I have 8 posts, but still want the 4 list elements limit?

Comment: you can limit your `if loop` to run for 4 times only.